QtCreator cannot find qt include files
I'm trying to build the latest version of qtnodes with qtcreator.

Windows 11

Visual studio 2022

Qt 6.7.1 MSVC2019 64 bit.

I don't see a version of qtnodes listed, but it was the latest as of 3/29/24

I also have the qt-vsaddin-msvc2022-x64-3.2.0-rev.47 although that probably isn't relevant.

Preferences/kit in qtcreator Name is set to Desktop Qt %{Qt:Version} MSVC2019 64bit


I followed the instructions for installing qt6. I followed the instructions for building qt nodes in qtcreator. The problem happens when I tell qtcreator to build qtnodes.
I get "Cannot open include file: 'QQMLApplicationEngine': No such file or directory
Not sure where it is looking. All the paths seem to be set up OK, as near as I can tell.
There is something weird about the QTNodesLibrary project. The project is called QTNodesLibrary. There seems to be two main.cpp files, each with a main method. One contains about a page and a half of code with a lot of references to QtNodes. The other contains about a third of a page of code and it looks like a barebones qt application, in a folder called QtQuickApplication1. No references to qtnodes. It is this second one which fails to compile. The second one includes two qt header files, QGUIApplication and QQmlApplicationEngine. The build process seems to find the first one and fails on the second.
I suspect that the smaller main.cpp shouldn't be there, but I didn't create this project. I just copied it from the distribution of qtnodes. Even if it shouldn't be there, it doesn't explain why qtcreator cannot find the include file.
So, several questions.

Has anyone run across this problem before or have suggestions on fixing it?
Are both main.cpp files supposed to be there (seems unlikely)?
How do I tell the exact path that qtcreator is using to locate the header files, especially QQmlApplicationEngine?

